# How to make comments multiple lines and one line in .wbt files used as world files in WeBots

Tags: comments, ros, webots

In WeBots and using programs with ROS2 you need to use world files with the .wbt extensions.

Does someone know how to comment one line or multiple lines ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `#` character in front of a line to comment it, like in Python.